# How to put table name as variable in select query without using prepare statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql

My code is working with this prepare statement but I don't want to use prepare statement... Please give me another solution

```
set @sql1 = concat('select *from ', @table_names,'');

PREPARE stmt1 from @sql1;
EXECUTE stmt1;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Thanks to all

Comment: AFAIK there is no alternative as yet - EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is still in the worklog

Comment: @CHill60 After using the execute immediate query. my db server goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers (e.g. table names) must be fixed in the query *before* the query is parsed.

So you cannot use as a table name:

- a variable
- a parameter
- a string expression
- result of a subquery
- etc.

You may only do what you're doing — write the new query as a string, and include the dynamic parts as a variable or an expression. Then you have a string, and you can prepare & execute that string. The parser has no way of knowing which parts of that string were originally a variable or an expression.